# Cancel new subscriptions if current one is not finished redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an epic action which fetches companies from a local server, dispatched in the `componentDidMount` method of a React component. 
With the returning data, I instantiate the models and pass them to the reducer which does its job.

The **epic action** looks like the following:

```
export const fetchCompaniesEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>): Observable<Action> =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(FETCH_COMPANIES),
        delay(5000),
        switchMap((action: any) =>
            ajax(COMPANIES_RESOURCE_URL).pipe(
                map((data: any) =>
                    data.response.map((value: any) => new Company(value.symbol, value.name, value.lastSale, value.marketCap, value.sector, value.industry))
                ),
                map((companies: Company[]) => fetchCompaniesFulfilled(companies))
            )
        )
    );
```

Being pretty new to `redux-observable`, I would like to ask 3 questions to all of you:

1) What is the best way to cancel all the new subscriptions (and so the http requests) which occur meanwhile the current one is still in progress? (in progress means also during the 5 seconds of delay)

2) What's the best way to achieve all my goal? Am I doing any bad practice or anything that could have been done better? (rxjs, react, redux)

3) What's the best way to subscribe also where I dispatch this action? Something like `dispatch({type: FETCH_COMPANIES}).subscribe`

p.s. This is just a theoretical example cause I would like to understand very well how it works so do not focus on the real utility of a delay etc...

Comment: I would prefer axios cancel subscription to make it functional.

Comment: @Sakhi Mansoor why? `rxjs` doesn't make it functional?

Comment: I meant functional programming. Why to make it observable

Comment: anyways it's our personal preferences.

Comment: your last comment is a knife to the heart of reactive programming

Comment: No I'm not hitting anyone. But why do we need it since JS alone can solve this

Comment: Being this the point, you don't need axios either, because JS alone can solve also its mission. The same for all the js libraries and frameworks

Comment: of course xhr Abort controller :) But I prefer axios which is built on cancellable promises concept

Comment: I won't use unless it becomes the necessity to my problem. But still it's personal choices. I wish you could fix like the way you're doing.

Comment: What do you mean by “cancel all requests”? Requests to what?

Comment: @Picci Sorry I meant to not execute the ajax ones which happen in the observable. Probably, I should have said "cancel all the new subscriptions"

Comment: Take a look at `exaustMap`

Comment: @quirimmo what exactly do you mean by AJAX request here? They’re network calls , ?

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate with some more details what @Xinan has written, you can consider the following example which aims to simulate your situation

```
const action$ = new Subject<number>();

const ajax = (delay: number) => {
    const ajax$ = new Subject<any>();
    setTimeout(() => {
        ajax$.next('delay ' + delay);
        ajax$.complete();
    }, delay);
    return ajax$.asObservable();
};

action$
.pipe(
    switchMap(delay => ajax(delay)),  // delay 1001, delay 1002
    // exhaustMap(delay => ajax(delay)),  // delay 3000, delay 1002
)
.subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(() => {action$.next(3000);}, 0);  // action$ emission 1
setTimeout(() => {action$.next(1000);}, 1000);  // action$ emission 2 
setTimeout(() => {action$.next(1001);}, 1500); // action$ emission 3
setTimeout(() => {action$.next(1002);}, 3502); // action$ emission 4
```

The `action$` Observable emits 4 times after 0, 1000, 1500 and 3502 milliseconds respectively.

Each time `action$` emits, we create an `ajax` Observable which itself will emit only once, after the delay specified as the `action$` parameter, and then completes.

So, for instance, the `ajax` Observable created by the first notification of `action$` (i.e. *action$ emission 1*) will emit after 3 seconds and will complete, while the second `ajax` Observable will emit after 2 seconds (1 second due to the delay of *action$ emission 2* + 1 second due to the delay with which `ajax` emits).

In this simulation, if you use `switchMap`, on the console you will see

```
delay 1001
delay 1002
```

The reason is that *action$ emission 3* emits while *action$ emission 1* and *action$ emission 2* are still on fly, and therefore they are completed and unsubscribed by *action$ emission 3* by the logic of `switchMap`. After *action$ emission 4* emits, there are no other *action$ emissions* and therefore it can complete normally, so that `diplay 1002` is printed on the console.

On the contrary, if you substitute `switchMap` with `exaustMap`, you will get

```
delay 3000
delay 1002
```

The reason is the mirror of the previous reasoning. *action$ emission 2* and *action$ emission 3* are killed because *action$ emission 1* is still on fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you need is `exaustMap`, basically it does the opposite of `switchMap`

`switchMap` cancels the previous one and take the new one instead

`exaustMap` cancels the new one and maintain the existing one if it's not done yet